# How do I convert a String or str& into a Vec<String>?

Tags: string, vector, split, rust

A function I want to use requires a `Vec<String>` as parameter input.

What I have instead is either a string slice (`&str`) or a `String`.

My attempt:

```
let options_vec: Vec<String> = options.split(char::is_withespace).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
value of type `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` returns `impl Iterator<Item = &str>`, you need explicitly convert its items to `String`, for example like this:

```rust
let options_vec: Vec<String> = options
    .split(char::is_whitespace)
    .map(ToString::to_string)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```